# Как задать быстрые действия в Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio (у меня 2015) имеет шаблоны для быстрых действий для разных ситуаций (исправление некоторых ошибок кода, автоматические вставки кода и др).

Так вот, есть, в том числе, быстрое действие "Инкапсулировать поле", которое для строки

```
string _someString;
```

создает обертку

```
public string SomeString
{
    get
    {
        return _someString;
    }
    set
    {
        _someString = value;
    }
}
```

Я хочу добавить еще одно быстрое действие для этой строки. Но где и как?